# Forward slash is not working in gdb

Tags: gdb

Iam using gdb version 6.8 on red hat linux.In my gdb forward slash(/) is not working.Whenever I press / key i get error bell.
       However it works properly for my friend who uses the same gdb version and our .gdbinit files are same.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> our `.gdbinit` files are same.

GDB uses the [GNU readline](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Readline) library, and that library uses `~/.inputrc` to control its behavior.

I am guessing that your `.inputrc`s are *not* the same.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer.It worked.to be specific the line which caused the problem is "set show-all-if-ambiguous on"